# Get cell reference for pivot table filter

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Does anyone know if its possible in VBA to find out which cell a pivot table filter is in ?  I cant see anything in the vba object model which tells me the worksheet location for a pivot table filter.

Comment: Maybe PageRange or PageRangeCell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, a cell object has a PivotField property if it contains a pivot field.   Simples!